# Is it possible to allow duplicate items entered into a TreeList control

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to create a template such that users can select multiple content items to appear on the page in a specific order. Basically my sitecore content is organized like this:

Workout Page - Contains a field called "Week 1 Workouts" (also week2, week3, week4, etc) which can have multiple Workouts (1 workout per day, basically)

Workout - Contains a field for a list of exercises (multiple exercises)

The problem I'm running into, is when setting up the "Week 1 Workout" field as a TreeList control, it won't allow me to reference multiple content items. For example, I would like to enter this content: [Workout 1, Workout 2, Workout 1, Workout 2, Rest, Workout 1, Workout 2]

However, the TreeList won't let me add Workout 1 or 2 more than once (some sort of javascript check). is there a way to disable the validation that content items can't appear more than once for the TreeList control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use:

AllowMultipleSelection in your source field

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Adding%20or%20removing%20items%20available%20within%20the%20TreeList%20field.aspx

so it would be something like:

/sitecore/content/Home/Workouts&AllowMultipleSelection=yes